# How Play ogg files in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

i use AudioClip class for playing ogg files but it says MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED .Is there any other libraries in javafx to play ogg files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this, worked for me

Check here: https://github.com/nnttoo/OggJavaPlayer

Comment: As far as I can see, the question is about JavaFX programs, and your application is not a JavaFX program.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX 8 contains no libraries for playing ogg files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is currently supported.

See the Javadoc for supported media types:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html

Please add a comment here:
https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18009

**Edit:**

> what about javaFX 2 ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html